# Angularjs orderBy based on multiple select menus

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to make orderBy based on multiple select menu. for example:

```
Order : 
<select ng-model="filterOrder">
    <option value="+">- to +</option>
    <option value="-">+ to -</option>
</select>

Column: 
<select ng-model="filterColumn">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="age">Age</option>
</select>

<div ng-repeat="user in users|orderBy:'filterOrder.filterColumn'">
        {{user.name}} {{user.age}}  <br>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the  `reverse` argument of `orderBy`

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users|orderBy:filterColumn: filterOrder == '-'">
```

The expression `filterOrder == '-'` will return a boolean for that argument